# Отключить проверку орфографии PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Раньше это делалось в Editor - Inspections - Spelling. Сейчас Spelling нет Inspections. Как теперь отключается проверка орфографии?

Версия PhpStorm 2020.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Над списком разделов в строке поиска укажите _spelling_ и вы получите список всех разделов, где это слово встречается - возможно это будет раздел **proofreading**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спеллчекер можно настроить в **Settings | Editor | Proofreading**, см. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/proofreading.html

Можете просто попробовать отключить инспекцию **Proofreading | Typo**